# Why does navigating to the Internet from a HyperlinkButton cause my app to crash?

Tags: hyperlink, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to display a privacy statement from a settings flyout using a HyperlinkButton; after clicking the hyperlink, though, I get a crash with two dialogs. The one on top says:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Warning
A debugger is attached to <ProjectName> but not configured to debug this  
unhandled exception. To debug this exception, detach the current debugger.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

...and below that the second dialog opines:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
An unhandled win32 exception occurred in <ProjectName> [10704].

Possible Debuggers:
New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio 2012
            Yes No
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

When I selected "No" to start that new instance, I was transferred away from the Emulator back to my debugging session - actually, the debugging session was terminated - it was as if I had Shift+F5'd.

My XAML is:

```
<HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Duckbilled Platypi Privacy Statement" NavigateUri="http://montereyscenics.posterous.com"/>
```

### UPDATE

So since the link worked fine in the AppSettings sample, I added an OnTapped event (admittedly, this is different than the OnClicked shown there) to the Hyperlink so that it now looks like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Time and Space Lines Privacy Statement" NavigateUri="http://montereyscenics.com/" Tapped="PrivacyHyperlink_OnTapped"/>
```

...and the handler:

```
async void PrivacyHyperlink_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(((HyperlinkButton)sender).Tag.ToString()));
}
```

It worked for a second - it immediately opened the page. But then it crashed on the "await" line (the only line) in the handler, with this missive:

"*System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=MetroSandboxPlaypen
  StackTrace:
       at MetroSandboxPlaypen.TandSLsSettings.d__0.MoveNext() in...*"

Comment: The [App Settings](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-settings-sample-1f762f49) sample has a similar scenario with a hyperlink in a flyout. If you add your NavigateUri to that sample, does it still fail?

Comment: It works fine from that sample; I see the Hyperlink there also has an OnClick event; other samples I saw didn't have that, so I didn't think it was necessary. I'll try that...

Comment: Updated my post with my results.

Comment: Where's the Tag property being set - isn't NavigateUri what you want there instead of Tag?

Comment: Can you show the code where you launch the fly out?

Comment: @Jim: I thought "Tag" looked kind of strange - that's what the App Settings sample uses. I originally had NavigateURI in my XAML until I saw the "official" way to do it was different.

Comment: @chue: The flyout launches fine, and everything else on it (comboBoxes) works.

Comment: When I first started, I'd launch my popups using a local Popup variable - it would launch ok, but would on occasion crash. It did this because the popup was a local variable and would go out of scope. I just thought maybe you might be doing the same thing.

Comment: yes, but the sample also has Tag="http://privacy.microsoft.com" set in the XAML. Your XAML isn't setting that property. Were you getting a NullReference when using NavigateUri vs. Tag in your event handler?

Comment: I added the Tag="privacy.microsoft.com" and it pretty much works now (the "Back" button for the browser doesn't take me back to my app; I have to Alt+Tab to do that). So, it seems one needs to have all of these properties set: Tag, NavigateUri, and Content - and an OnTapped event handler to actually open the link.